# bash command to remove new lines if condition on the next line is met

Tags: regex, perl, newline

I have the following file

`cat file.txt`

```
Alex
Josh
c.ab23
Shawn
c.a13
c.oq42
Allie
c.ba212
```

I would like to replace the new lines with a tab only if the next line starts with `c.` as follows:

```
Alex
Josh    c.ab23
Shawn   c.a13   c.oq42
Allie   c.ba212
```

I thought something similar to

`perl -pe 's/\nc\./\t/g'`

Though I guess perl reads line by line. Is there another simple command that would do this?

Comment: Next command should do it `perl -0777 -pe 's/\n(c\.)/\t$1/g' file.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your perl command can operate on the whole text at once with the [-0777 switch](https://perldoc.pl/perlrun#-0%5Boctal/hexadecimal%5D):

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\n(?=c\.)/\t/g' file.txt
```

(and in-place, if you add the [-i switch](https://perldoc.pl/perlrun#-i%5Bextension%5D))

Comment: You have removed `c.` which is still present in desired output. Probably you  meant `perl -0777 -pe 's/\n(c\.)/\t$1/g' file.txt` instead.

Comment: Just wondering what -0777 does? As far as I know, `file.txt` must be a set of ASCII bytes, so I am not certain as to why new lines are treated differently by most bash commands

Comment: @user171558 The linked documentation explains the option - `-p` operates line by line by default, `-0` lets you change this delimiter in various ways.

Comment: As for why `-p`, and many unix utilities operate by line - it's the most convenient default for a large number of text processing tasks.

Comment: Please visit the following [webpage](https://www.perl.com/pub/2004/08/09/commandline.html/) and look for 0777 option (read whole file into variable, in this case variable is $_).

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/^c\./ {P=P"\t"$0; next} {if (P) print P; P=$0} END {if (P) print P}' < file.txt
```

Outputs

```
Alex
Josh    c.ab23
Shawn   c.a13   c.oq42
Allie   c.ba212
```