# Replace newline if condition is met in next line in text file with linux command line tools

Tags: regex, bash, perl

Input

```
$ cat input.txt
345 "cuad"  "dfr"
23  "test3" "dfec2
"v1"
33 v2
v3"
32  "key3"  "fer"
12  "rte"   "ef"
```

Goal, I would like to replace the newline with a space only if the next line not starts with number and tab

```
345 "cuad"  "dfr"
23  "test3" "dfec2 "v1" 33 v2 v3"
32  "key3"  "fer"
12  "rte"   "ef"
```

trying this
[bash command to remove new lines if condition on the next line is met](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60516458/18749361)
but I can't adapt it to my needs

Attempt, it doesn't work

```
$ perl -0777 -pe 's/\n(?=[^0-9]+\t)/ /g' input.txt
```

Comment: "New line" is not the same as "newline".

Comment: This looks like it might be a case of broken tsv, with quoted fields that contain newlines and unescaped quotes?

Comment: yes, it is the problem of openstreetmap data, in the values they put carriage returns emojis, quotes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `perl` command with a negative lookahead:

```bash
perl -0777 -pe 's/\R(?!\d+\t|\Z)/ /g' file

345 "cuad"  "dfr"
23  "test3" "dfec2 "v1" 33 v2 v3"
32  "key3"  "fer"
12  "rte"   "ef"
```

- [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pfzQb9/1)
- [Code Demo](https://ideone.com/30fyh2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\R`: Match any line break character (unicode compliant)
- `(?!\d+\t|\Z)`: Negative lookahead to assert that we don't have 1+ digits followed by a tab OR end of input ahead

Comment: Hi sir, I tried this command in my Linux machine with perl's version `v5.26.3` but its not working and giving output in a single line itself. I have checked there are NO control M characters in file, any thought on same sir, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: I have added a regex demo and code demo in my answer. Note that there are tabs in each line.

Answer (score 2):

Without slurping:

```bash
perl -pe'
   chomp;
   if ( /^\d+\t/ ) {
      print "\n" if $. > 1;
   } else {
      print "\t";
   }
   END { print "\n" if $. > 0; }
'
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative in `GNU sed`:

```
sed ':a; N; /\n[0-9][0-9]*\t/{P;D;}; s/\n/ /; ba' file
```

Please note that this command is specific to GNU `sed`.